# runtime variable type list

Tags: c++, templates

I have a databalse-file:

```
[id] [name] [is_male]
1 John true
2 Pete true
3 Emma false
...
```

I want to fetch row from file and save it in memory. Number of columns and type of columns to be determined at runtime. Symbolic usage:

```
class Row;

Row row = fetch();

int id = row[0];
float a = row[0];  // runtime error?
short b = row[0];  // integral type, should work fine
bool is_male = row[2];
```

What container should I use?

Comment: research `std::variant` and `std::any`, then put one of those in an `std::vector`, possibly nested.

Comment: just a note, unless `row[0]` return some kind of proxy, it would not return different type because it's lhs.